# When to replace the timing belt on a 2015 VW Golf TDI

Tags: vw, diesel, golf, belt, timing

I own a VW Golf TDI 1.6 Mk7 (2015) Odometer: 82,000KM.  I would like to know at what Odometer reading should I change the timing belt/chain.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You may be able to find this information in your owners manual

Answer (score 1):

This information is typically found in the owners manual.
That said, newer VW diesel engines like your EA288 use a 'lifetime' belt. According to VW it only needs to be replaced every 100-130K miles / 160-200K kilometers.

Comment: Most specs also set a time limit. Is there one in this case?

Comment: @David well i the owner looks it up in the owners manual we would know. Anyway i cannot imagine that a 'lifetime' timing belt already needs replacement after three years.

Comment: Not everyone has an owners manual, and it is not always accurate.  For example A4 TDIs came with 80k belts and if replaced with newer belts the new interval is 100k.  That said, MadMarky posted information which I understand to be correct, and I upvote.

Comment: Perhaps 130k seems like a lifetime, compared with the older 80k mile belts.  Or the marketing people got creative.